# Protractor: How can I wait until the next AngularJS digest starts?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-digest

I need this for **events fired by the server** which arrive at my websocket connection: As soon as the event arrives, the AngularJS digest starts.

Example: I expect an event in 1-5 seconds. How can I make protractor wait for the digest triggered by the event, *and* wait until the digest is over?

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what you're trying to achieve? There are ways to wait X number of seconds and there are ways to wait for elements to appear on the page, but I don't think either of these are what you're after.

Comment: On our testing machine, the browser can become quite slow. Thus if the test does something (for instance save a record in a form) which produces a server-side event that travels to the browser, I can be 100% sure the event will reach the browser within the next 30 seconds, but not (e.g.) within the next 300 ms. Thus I need to await a digest triggered by the event coming from the server, and then proceed with my testing steps. It is like Protractor's "wait for angular", but arbitrarily delayed. Let's call it "wait until angular wakes up and then wait for angular".

Comment: Sounds like you want [browser.wait()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait)

Comment: `browser.wait()` would have to wait 30 seconds. That is too slow. Wait must be dynamic.

Comment: `browser.wait()` can be configured to wait until a promise is returned. Alternatively, you can use [protractor.ExpectedConditions](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions)

Comment: I confused it with `browser.sleep()`, but how can I wait for the next digest?